# Keycloak admin client get 404 HTTP error when getting access token

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, keycloak-admin-client

i'm using keycloak with quarkus and in my integration test i'm using dev service to build keycloak server. My problem is taht when i want to get access token with keycloak admin client i get 404 HTTPand at the same time when i'm using postman i get the token.

My class:

```
package com.smartech.shopping.backend.bank.controller;

import com.smartech.shopping.backend.bank.controller.mapper.ErrorMapper;
import com.smartech.shopping.backend.bank.controller.rest.AuthenticationApi;
import com.smartech.shopping.backend.bank.entity.CredentialDto;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.OAuth2Constants;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@ApplicationScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationApiImpl implements AuthenticationApi {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url")
    String serverUrl;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.keycloak.realm-name")
    String realm;
    private final ErrorMapper errorMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ErrorMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response authentication(CredentialDto credentialDto) {
        try(Keycloak keycloak =
                    KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                            .clientId(credentialDto.getClientId())
                            .clientSecret(credentialDto.getClientSecret())
                            .realm(realm)
                            .serverUrl(serverUrl)
                            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                            .build()){
            return Response
                    .ok(keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken())
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

My application.properties

```
##----------TEST----------------##
%test.quarkus.keycloak.admin-client.enabled=true
%test.quarkus.keycloak.admin-client.server-url=http://localhost:8080
%test.quarkus.keycloak.admin-client.realm=quarkus
%test.quarkus.keycloak.admin-client.client-id=quarkus
%test.quarkus.keycloak.admin-client.client-secret=secret
%test.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled=true
%test.quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=iJZaGcPoHhkccbs9mLo4Mhu1w0TmamZl
%test.quarkus.keycloak.devservices.realm-path=realms/shopping-realm.json
%test.quarkus.keycloak.realm-name=quarkus

##----------PROD----------------##
%prod.quarkus.oidc.token-path=/protocol/openid-connect/token
%prod.quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/shopping-realm
```

And my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-authorization</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In the tutorial they use quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson and i'm using quarkus-resteasy-jackson. I don't know if it,s the problem.

Ùthank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the properties quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url and quarkus.keycloak.realm-name. I set them correctly and it is working find now